# What's a word for the fear of eating hot peppers?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the fear of eating hot peppers? By hot peppers, I mean fruits from plants that are members of the Capsicum genus of the Solanaceae family that contain capsaicin to any noticeable degree, or have an SHU rating greater than 0. This question does not pertain to temperature or flavor.

Example sentence (where [x] represents the word): "Ever since he had licked a chile pepper as a child, he had maintained a moderate case of [x]."

Comment: Common sense?  Pain avoidance?  I don't think there is a single word for wanting to avoid pain.  Maybe antimasochism?

Comment: Thank God knowing there's someone in the world who hates food that contain chilli, i can tolerate black pepper, but the smell, texture, and sights of chilli inside food is a turn off to me but i can tolerate spices

Comment: Some people have coined the word ["chiliphobia"](https://fearof.org/chiliphobia/) but it isn't in dictionaries and it mixes a Nahuatl root with a Greek one, so etymologists will cry (even more than they'll cry after a plate of chili). But if you're not looking for a word that's in dictionaries, that's fine (and I don't think the ancient Greeks had a word for chili.)

Comment: Do you really want a word specific to the Capsicum genus, or something covering fear of all spicy-hot foods?

Comment: @nnnnnn Hot peppers only, but in the absence of the existence of one, I wouldn't mind hearing about more general stuff. It's been a really long time; so, I just accepted the answer given.

Comment: @StuartF In actual practice, I'd probably use that. People would know what it meant, whether or not it's officially a word. Might as well get the ball rolling to give it more impact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a specific phobia terminology for "*fear of eating hot peppers that are members of the Capsicum genus of the Solanaceae family that contain capsaicin to any noticeable degree, or have an SHU rating greater than 0*".

But the blanket phobia for **spices** and **spicy food** seems to be [***Aromaphobia***](http://phobia.wikia.com/wiki/Aromaphobia)

> Aromaphobia (from Latin aroma, meaning "spice") is the fear of spices and spicy food. This phobia most often came about due to burning sensation in the mouth when having spicy food in it. The less common trigger is that spices can cause heartburn. Sufferers would avoid spicy foods at all cost, as they would not sprinkle pepper onto food. If they unknowingly eat food that is spicy, they would spit the food out and gulp on water in terror.

[Phobia Wiki]

Comment: Although this answer is correct, I do not like the word "aromaphobia" to describe the "fear of spicy food" or the "fear of spice". Maybe chili-phobia is better :)